# inflate image to fill modal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to inflate an image to occupy the entirety of a modal in the center of a screen. I would like to preserve the aspect ratio of the image (not squish or stretch it), but at the same time have the image be as wide / tall as possible up to the max-width and max-height as defined on a parent container.

Is this possible with CSS or do I have to use Javascript to determine the dimensions?

```css
.ng-modal-dialog {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>In this example, I'd want a taller image that's narrower, but I'm not sure how to make the image correctly "inflate" to fill either the height or the width depending on which maxes out first.</p>
<p>In this example, the image is too tall, and fills the width but overflows out the sides.</p>
<div class="ng-modal-dialog">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That image is pretty large, so you could potentially use some basic HTML attributes on the img tag, or use CSS styles to changes it by class.

I made a JSfiddle for you "zm7y9200" explaining it with demonstrations below in the stackoverflow code inclusion:

```css
/*
    If you alternatively wanted to define a class for these images, in the
    event you were to need several you could do that as follows and class
    your modal images with the css below in the class name you'd prefer.
*/

.imgsClassNameYouWant{
    size: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.brachadesigns.com/design/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/raster_vs_vector.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" alt="scalability"/>

<!--What you have to be careful of, is whatever parent element is bounding this element and therefore the inherited styles. This could be regulated by a style sheet such as bootstrap without your knowing.  To override this, you could define inline styles thought it's a bit more intuitive to do it in the CSS and class the image elements you wish to size. -->


<p>In this example, I'd want a taller image that's narrower, but I'm not sure how to make the image correctly "inflate" to fill either the height or the width depending on which maxes out first.</p>
<p>In this example, the image is too tall, and fills the width but overflows out the sides.</p>
<a href="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/" target="_new">Try this link to AngularUI's bootstrap documentation</a>
<div class="ng-modal-dialog"> 
    <!-- FYI, without including links to angular, angularUI, jQuery, and bootstrap for angular, this is useless in your stackoverflow snippet example. -->
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg"></img>
</div>
<h2> So below is sort of your solution, and it's pretty simplistic</h2>
<h3> You can solve your issue simply by calling the image "size" attribute 100%,
     defining the "height" attribute as "100%", and then altering the "width" 
    attribute to 50% in the <pre> "img" tag as shown here below in code. </pre>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg" size="100%" height="100%" width="50%"></img>
    </hr>
<p> Below is the same image, but style in the CSS as the "imgsClassNameYouWant" class. </p>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg" class="imgsClassNameYouWant"></img>
```

Hope it helps!